# ConversionException: Unparseable date on Jasper reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm working on a system that uses Jasper reports. Recently it started throwing this error:

```
org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException: Unparseable date: "03/03/1981"
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.locale.BaseLocaleConverter.convert(BaseLocaleConverter.java:241)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.locale.LocaleConvertUtilsBean.convert(LocaleConvertUtilsBean.java:285)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractTextDataSource.convertStringValue(JRAbstractTextDataSource.java:69)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource.getFieldValue(JRXmlDataSource.java:313)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:823)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:787)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1478)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:125)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:942)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:860)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:84)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:624)
        at XmlJasperInterface.report(XmlJasperInterface.java:89)
        at XmlJasperInterface.main(XmlJasperInterface.java:63)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "03/03/1981"
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRDateLocaleConverter.parse(JRDateLocaleConverter.java:84)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.locale.BaseLocaleConverter.convert(BaseLocaleConverter.java:232)
        ... 13 more
```

I'm not sure what caused it. We've also recently upgraded Jasper reports but I remember it was working after the upgrade.

I've found a blog post titled [BeanUtils, Digester, and Type Conversion](http://radio.javaranch.com/jason/2004/06/09/1086797433000.html) which points to add these lines:

```
String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
DateLocaleConverter converter = new DateLocaleConverter(locale, pattern);
converter.setLenient(true);
ConvertUtils.register(converter, java.util.Date.class);
```

but they've changed nothing. I still get the same error.

The line that triggers the error is this one:

```
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, new JRXmlDataSource(System.in, selectCriteria));
```

Thanks.

**Update**: Downgrading Jasper Reports to 1.1.0 made it work again, so it was most likely the upgrade that broke it.

Comment: What are your locale settings? For the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy" I would use Locale.US instead of Locale.getDefault which gives you current OS Locale.

Comment: Pawel, my locale is de_CH, but even writing the date as d.m.yyyy didn't help. I've tried all major date formats and none worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to set a date pattern in your datasource, like this:

```
JRXmlDataSource datasource = new JRXmlDataSource(....);
datasource.setDatePattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: can you provide some of the "why" behind your answer? Is the date getting interpreted incorrectly as a String until he creates a dataSource for it?